# Redis Persistence Partial

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisclient

I have multiple keys in redis most of which are insignificant and can be lost in case my redis server goes down.

However I have one or two keys, which I cannot afford to lose. 
Hence I would like that whenever the server restarts, redis reads only these few keys from its persistent storage, and keep on persisting these as and when they change.

Does redis have this feature? If yes what command makes a key persisted to file and how to differ b/w persisted and unpersisted keys.

If no, What approach can I use such that I need not make my own persistent file before writing to Redis

Limitations(If the answer is no)

1. I do not want to change client code that enters in redis.
2. I cannot add more servers to redis(if any such solution exists, would like to know about it though).

**EDIT**
Another reason I would not want to save most keys as persistence because it is huge data, hundreds of records per second- Most of which expires in 10 minutes.

Comment: have a look here http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: No, but how often do these keys "important" get updated?

Comment: Lets say once daily (so can I take that the answer is NO?)

Comment: To be precise the answer is NO. persistence settings is for the whole redis instance. IMO best option is to use a seperate instance.